# Adding elements to Mindmap/ Horizontal tree

Tags: app.diagrams.net

This may be a basic question, but I could not figure it out even after spending a while on it and the documentation.

How do I add new elements/nodes to a mindmap/horizontal tree?

The blue arrow lets you duplicate the same element (like I've done for *Topic*) but I can't seem to figure how to add for instance a *branch* from the *Topic* like in the figure below:
[image: Mind Map example]

Is there any documentation that I may have overlooked on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://about.draw.io/organization-charts-and-mind-maps-in-draw-io/

Comment: Thanks @David I went through the page again after you mentioned it. I figured how to do it after that but it is not clearly captured on that page though. The solution is to hold ```Ctrl``` and drag and drop the required shape on the node where it is to be inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the [page](https://about.draw.io/organization-charts-and-mind-maps-in-draw-io/) again after David mentioned it. I figured how to do it after that but it is not clearly captured on that page though.

The solution is to hold `Ctrl` and drag and drop the required shape on the node where it is to be inserted.

Comment: Although, I'm still not sure if there's a way (a shortcut perhaps) to keep adding new  branches